# Tag synonyms fish-tank and aquarium

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms

[aquarium](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aquarium)
[fish-tank](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fish-tank)

are both used to describe indoor fish containers.

I propose to make them synonyms. While I think that a fish-tank describes something bigger than an aquarium, the practical difference seem to be small.

Comment: I would tend to agree, from a pet perspective they're probably interchangeable.

Comment: Which one do we want to be the synonym? This will be the one actually applied to questions.

Comment: 'Aquarium' would be the more-likely used term in the context of this forum.

Comment: In addition to what Robert said, all fish tanks are aquariums (AFAIK) but not all aquariums are fish tanks (sometimes they hold reptiles), so if that distinction ever matters then aquarium should be the main tag.

Comment: [tag:aquarium-fish], [tag:aquarium-reptile]